# Running Azure Service Fabric as different user

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Am trying to run my Service Fabric application in my local cluster to run as a different user. Use case is am trying to connect to my on prem database, but since n/w service accounts don't have access, i need to run my SF as logged in user. I've followed the below url exactly, as Admin user & domain user, but no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security

Am getting the below error in eventviewer.
"Error getting user account information for domain\user:AccessDenied"
"SetupSecurityPrincipals failed with ApplicationPrincipalAbortable Error"

How else can i run my SF as logged in user?

Comment: You should add the applicationmanifest.xml to check if you did it right, otherwise won't help just pointing you to the docs.

Comment: Check that the default ASF user has permissions to read the Domain tree. This was the issue in my case, and took me a few days to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by running 'Service Fabric Host Service' in services as logged in user(instead of local account). Along with this the Integrated Security = SSPI needs to be in the appsettings.json.